# HTML/CSS - resize dynamically iframe without using javascript

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm using a javascript to resize an iframe relative to its content.
The goal is to display the content and using the scroll of the parent of the iframe only.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <iframe name="tht" width="100%" src="path" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'></iframe>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

I want to have the same behavior without using javascript (only css).

I tried to use `height="100%"` but the scroll of the iframe appears.

**Edit:** I don't have a problem to use a javascript solution, but sometimes the iframe resizing takes a long time and sometimes the resizing doesn't work: there is no display.

Comment: does your iframe have any absolute or fixed positioned or floated elements?

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/" 
        class="iframe" 
        width="100%" 
        height="400px" 
        scrolling="no" 
        frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

You can use above in this there is `width="100%"` specified but the height will be fixed.

You can try by resizing your browser.

Comment: I modified 'heigth' to 100% butthe iframe doesn't disply all the content. And its appears that 'scrolling' is obsolete in HTML5